# php function gives a loop - hostfact API

Tags: php, loops

I'm using hostfact https://www.hostfact.nl for our billing. Now I want to extend the code and get a loop on executing the internalAPI in hooks.php. I tried to find an answer in the documentation https://www.hostfact.nl/developer/api/ but without success.

```
// When a client is edited, the bankParameters are checked and validated.
// That is only an example
function action_debtor_is_edited($parameters){
     
    $params     = array(
                        'DebtorCode' => $parameters['DebtorCode']
                        );
    $hostfactResult = internalAPI('debtor', 'show', $params);
    
    $bankParams = array(
                        'Identifier'    => '2',
                        'AccountNumber' => 'AT6734080000000000',
                        'AccountBank'   => 'test bank',
                        'AccountCity'   => 'city',
                        'AccountBIC'    => 'RLNODASD'
                        );
                
    $bankResult = internalAPI('debtor', 'edit', $bankParams); 
}
```

I've already asked the support and got follwoing answer:

> One of the option is keeping track of the situation. For example, use
> a static or global variable. When you call an (internal)API call from
> a webhook, first flag that variable, so in the newly called webhook
> you know that is not needed to execute the webhook again (at least not
> the part which causes the loop). In the original call, after receiving
> the result, the flag can be unset again.

My Problem is, I'm new to PHP and don't understand what I should do to avoid the loop. The $bankParams variable is intentionally hardcoded.
Can you help?

Comment: What is `interalAPI` doing?

Comment: @darkbee Within webhooks you can use the internal API. Via the internal API you can make API calls without making a cURL request. The API command is executed directly within HostFact and is therefore faster.
The internal API uses exactly the same input and output as the external API. The only difference is calling the API, this is done via an "internalAPI ()" function.

Comment: Well in the posted code u gave, I don't see a loop at first?

Comment: @darkbee Me neither.... thats why I dont't see the error...